# Manjaro Linux takes much longer to load when no other hard drive is connected

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, ssd, manjaro

I added a new SSD to my PC and I'm having troubles with the loading speed of Manjaro Linux. I'm trying to understand what's going on and what could be the issue.
The steps I followed are:

1. Unplug Windows hard drive from SATA3 connector(to not mess up things and make the process easier)
2. Plug the SSD to another SATA3 connector
3. Boot from USB (with Manjaro inside) connected to the motherboard
4. Follow installation instructions, to install Manjaro into the SSD (including personal partitioning: GPT instead of MBR, partitions sizes, and mount points)
5. Install the SO in the selected ext4 partition mounted on '/'.
6. Restart and boot Manjaro.

Without the USB installer plugged in and neither the Windows Hard Drive, Manjaro takes aprox. 1min to load, and no GRUB appears.

With the Windows Hard Drive and Manjaro SSD, both connected, it takes aprox. 10sec and the GRUB apperars fine. The GRUB is the one that comes with Manjaro (I know it just because it has Manjaro gui as background)

Update: Yes, maybe it's the searching of Windows that causes the delay. And thx for point that SMART will not address this issue, I already searched around and found nothing.

Comment: Check the SMART data of the SSD.

Comment: 1. You describe installing Manjaro while the SSD was connected via USB.  Later you describe both drives connected via SATA.  Just to confirm, you used an external enclosure or adapter to install Manjaro, then mounted it internally?  2. When Manjaro takes 1 min, is all of that time spent actively loading the OS, or is a chunk of it "pre-boot" hardware enumeration and the like?  3. How does the computer decide which OS to boot when both drives are connected?  GRUB wouldn't know about Windows; do you need to select the boot device at power-on?  (cont'd)

Comment: If you updated GRUB after installation so you get to Windows through GRUB, having only the SSD connected will create a delay while GRUB goes searching for Windows, which it thinks is supposed to be there.  4. If you can boot from the SSD in 10 sec when the Windows drive is connected, the issue when that drive isn't connected isn't something SMART will address.

Comment: Please click [edit] and advise the make and model of your PC/motherboard, and in which SATA III the SSD is connected. I have run into isses with specific motherboards and specific SATA ports when there's a M.2 module installed. Is there one? Please click [edit] and advise. Also, please do not click Add Comment as when comments pile up (as they are), old comments get pushed off-screen. As soon as I see you've put that info in your question, I will remove this Comment to make room for others. You can delete your Comment directly above mine as I put your info into the Question.